# Exporting plot to pdf in R: Adds legend to second page but not first page

Tags: r

When I export my plot to pdf and add a legend, the pdf comes out as two pages, page 1 has the plot without the legend, and page 2 has the plot with the legend.

How do I adjust my code so that I only end up with one pdf (the plot + the legend)?

Here is my code:

`pdf("52_week_moving_average_chart.pdf")
plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg)
addLegend("topleft",lty = 1,cex=1.2)
dev.off()`

And here is a picture of what happens when I make the pdf:

[page 1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9GeJ.jpg

[page 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/APBRp.jpg

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your "plot" line above the "pdf" line.

i.e. like this:

```
plot(fifty_twoweekmovavg)
pdf("52_week_moving_average_chart.pdf",onefile=TRUE)
addLegend("topleft",lty = 1,cex=1.2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this?